# How do I print data

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code but it runs without any results, I have a table "sliders " that contains id and URL for image and I'm sure connect.php is fine.

```
<?php
    $sliders=array();
    include"connect.php";
    $query_getinfo="select * from sliders";
    $result=$connect->prepare($query_getinfo);
    $result->execute();
    
    while($row=$result->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $record=array();
    $record["id"]=$row["id"];
    $record["slide_url"]=$row["slide_url"];
    
    $slider[]=$record;
    
    //$sliders[]=$row["slide_url"];
    
    }
    
   print_r ($sliders);

?>
```

Comment: `$slider[]` != `$sliders`

Comment: No need to use `prepare()` here, `query()` would work just fine, you aren't sending any variables to your database. (Not using `prepare()` means you also don't need `execute()`.)

Comment: oh , thanks thats a lol mistake

Comment: and i also have another question with this , how can i send this array with json to my android app , i want to use this for retrofit

Comment: just do it `echo json_encode($sliders);` instead of print_r

Comment: thank you is there any diffrentiate between JSON_encode and json_encode

Comment: @Mitra Function names are case-insensitive so it doesn't matter if you write JSON_encode or json_encode. It's just the same but preference is usually lower case

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you do not have any parameters to pass so you can just replace prepare with query and remove execute, below are 2 examples

if you want to pass parameters

```
// prepare the query
$sliders = array();

$statement = $connect->prepare("select * from sliders WHERE type = ?");

// assuming type is string eg admin / user

$statement->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['type']);
// execute it
$statement->execute();

// ger result
$result = $statement->get_result();

// check if rows exists in table
if($result->num_rows > 0){

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $record=array();
     $record["id"]=$row["id"];
     $record["slide_url"]=$row["slide_url"];
     $sliders[]=$record;
   }

   print "<pre";
   print_r($sliders);

}else{ 
  print "no sliders found";
}

$statement->close();
```

if you do not have parameters in query

```
$sliders = array();

// prepare the query

$result = $connect->query("select * from sliders");

// check if rows exists in table
if($result->num_rows > 0){

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $record=array();
     $record["id"]=$row["id"];
     $record["slide_url"]=$row["slide_url"];
     $sliders[]=$record;
   }

   print "<pre";
   print_r($sliders);

}else{ 
  print "no sliders found";
}

// if you want to close connection here.
$connect->close();
```